# In Python, why won't something print without a newline?

Tags: python, posix

```
import time
import sys
sys.stdout.write("1")
time.sleep(5)
print("2")
```

will print "12" after 5 seconds

```
import time
import sys
sys.stdout.write("1\n")
time.sleep(5)
print("2")
```

will print "1\n" right away, then "2" after 5 seconds

Why is this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you add "\n" then stream is flushed automaticaly, and it is not without new line at the end.
You can flush output with:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: I upvoted all the answers except yours because it is the less explanatory

Answer (score 9):

Because `stdout` is buffered. You may be able to force the output sooner with a `sys.stdout.flush()` call.

Answer (score 5):

The sys.stdout.write command from the sys module purposefully prints out the statement without the \n character. This is how a normal call to the stdout stream works, such as in C++ or C, where the \n character must be added manually.

However the print command provided by Python automatically adds a \n character to the string, therefore simplifying the code and making it easier to read.

The reason the phenomenon in the first result happens is because the system is waiting for a flush to print out, which is provided by the \n character. You can avoid this by using this command, `sys.stdout.flush()`, which will flush the stdout stream which forces it to print.

Answer (score 4):

*Buffering*. It's not really Python, but rather your operating system/terminal. Output from any program is sent to a *buffer*, a holding area of memory. When a whole line is collected, it's sent to the screen. There is usually a hook, a method named something like `flush()`, to force output of partial lines.

Answer (score 4):

It's because output in Python is buffered by default - ordinarily you won't get the output until the buffer is full or something causes the buffer to be flushed. In this case the `\n` was sensed and caused an automatic flush.

See this question for ways around the problem: [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Answer (score 1):

Consider that when you type a command into a computer, it doesn't know *you're finished* until you press ENTER

Similarly, the newline tells Python you've finished that line.